# Choose elements based on odds without going through entire list to compute the probability

Tags: java, statistics, probability

Let's say we're given an array of some number of objects, each one having a certain weight representing its ratio of being chosen to the other elements. So, for instance, if you have one object of weight 10, one of weight 30, and one of weight 35, the ratio is 10:30:35. The probability of the first object being chosen should be 10/75 = 13.3%, the probability of the second being chosen should be 30/75 = 40%, and the probability of the third being chosen should be 35/75 = 46.6%

Now, let's say we have a function that's given this array and has to return a randomly-chosen object based on its weight. The brute force way to do this is to go over each object with a for loop and add its weight to some total, then go over the loop again and see whether each object should be chosen according to some random probability function:

```
int totalWeight = 0;

for(Object o: array) {
  totalWeight += o.weight;
}

//Now we have the total weight
for(Object o in array) {
  /* randomProb(double x) is some function which only returns true x percent of the time */
  if(randomProb(o.weight / totalWeight)) {
    return o;
  }
}
```

But let's say we're dealing with thousands of inputs, so that iterating over each one twice is cost-intensive. Is there a simpler algorithm for determining which object to return without having to go over the loop once to find the total weight, and then go over it again on each element?

Comment: Are you dealing with the same set of inputs multiple times with the same weights?

Comment: The inputs contain different fields which may have varying values. The values are mostly in a small range, so there may be some inputs that are identical except for their weight.

Comment: But my question was whether you were trying to fetch multiple random options for the same set of weights - in which case you could do some "pre-work" and then use that to efficiently pick each time.

Comment: Guess I misunderstood what you were asking. No, the weights are random, but within the same range.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean... it's not about a single range, but do you have one set of weights, which is then used to fetch multiple random values? Or will you have a different set of weights each time?

Comment: The weights are always different, but they'll always be in the same range, for instance, between 1 and 10.

Comment: That doesn't help much, as the total is going to vary. There *may* be a way of only going through the data once, but it would mean generating a lot more random numbers. Is it really a problem to go through the data twice?

Comment: It's not a huge issue to do it twice, but I was just thinking there must be a more efficient way to do this, seeing as it's not an uncommon issue in computer science.

Comment: "It's not an uncommon thing to want to do" doesn't logically lead to "there must be an efficient way of doing it". As I say, I think there's probably a way of doing it with a single pass if you're *also* happy to generate a random number for each data points, but if you've only got thousands of data points, that's likely to be less efficient than just storing them all in memory and going through them twice.

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet, you are almost certainly going to be better off speed wise to do this in two passes.  First pass total up the weights, second pass select the element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in one pass, but you need to sample `n - 1` uniform random variables, where `n` is the length of the list.  We can't say if that's actually better in your case or not with out knowing a lot more details about your application.

I would guess that switching to a one pass algorithm won't generally offer much speed benefit, but could be useful if your list is too long to fit into memory.

The algorithm (note that I'm using 1-relative indexing), for a list with elements `x[1], x[2], ..., x[n]`, with positive weights `w[1], w[2], ..., w[n]`.

Pseudo code (sorry, not in java but you should be able to convert it):

```
x = x[1]
w_total = w[1]

for i in 2..n
    w_total = w_total + w[i]
    if (SampleUniform(0, 1) < w[i] / w_total)
       x = x[i]
```

I'm assuming that `SampleUniform(0, 1)` samples a continuous uniform (0, 1) random variable.  After the `for` loop completes, `x` is now a sample from the list `x[1], x[2], ..., x[n]` with the desired property.  Specifically

```
Probability(x = x[i]) = w[i] / w_total
```

where

```
w_total = Sum(j = 1..n) w[j].
```

It's relatively simple to see why this works by examining what's happening inside the `for` loop for an arbitrary `i` and using proof by induction.  Suppose that the current `x = x[j]` has been sampled from the list `x[1], ..., x[i - 1]` with probability `w[j] / Sum(k = 1 to i - 1) w[k]` (we'll deal with this in the next section).  The new `w_total` will be equal to `Sum(k = 1 to i) w[i]` and it should be clear that after sampling the uniform random variable that we will have

```
Probability(x = x[i]) = w[i] / w_total
```

and

```
Probability(x = x[j]) = w[j] / (Sum(k = 1 to i - 1) w[k]) * 
                        Sum(k = 1 to i - 1) w[k] / w_total 
                      = w[j] / w_total.
```

Since both `j` and `i` were arbitrary it holds that after each step in the for loop, `x` will satisfy the property

```
Probability(x = x[k]) = w[k] / w_total for k in 1 ... i.
```

It should be easy to see that this approach will be correct for a list of a single element (this addresses the above 'suppose' statement).  Hence by induction, after the for loop

```
Probability(x = x[i]) = w[i] / w_total
```

where

```
w_total = Sum(j = 1..n) w[j].
```

(so the algorithm works).

All that being said, I don't know if this is a good idea (speedwise) for lists that will fit in memory.  I doubt it, sampling `n - 1` uniform random numbers may take more time than looping through the list a second time (you can do some speed tests to check this).